# Custom post type - archive

Tags: php, wordpress

I have custom post type for wordpress.

```
http://localhost/wordpress/photos/
http://localhost/wordpress/photos/my-photo
```

Why these url return 404 not found ?

How can I make a archive file for this ?
like :

 archive-photos.php ( I have this in directory, but ...)

```
function register_gallery(){
    register_post_type( 'photos', array(
        'public'            => true,
        'menu_position'     => 10,
        'menu_icon'     => 'dashicons-format-gallery',
        'supports'      => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail'),
        'has_archive'       => true,

    ));
}

add_action('init','register_gallery');
```

Comment: I would suggest , take reference from woocommerce, the products are custom posts.I have done it for custom product types.

Comment: i'm not using any plugin !

Comment: How the permalinks are set in Settings > Reading ?

Comment: I have not asked you to use plugin, I have only asked you to take reference from that, you can use templates in your theme folder.Even you know ,you can use woocommerce template in your theme folder, like that make custom template for your post type and use that inside your theme folder.

Comment: with permalink solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use,

```
//Need to call when custom post type is being used
flush_rewrite_rules();
```

also try, settings->permalinks save all settings.

more info visit, https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type

Comment: Visiting permalinks page is the same as using `flush_rewrite_rules()`

Comment: @JayDeepNimavat Why that? `init` hook is perfectly fine for register post type. From [WP Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type): "register_post_type should only be invoked through the 'init' action"

Answer (score 0):

I found another solution, it can be done on 404 page when navigating through archives on custom post type(CPT):

```
/**
 * My cpt is storytitle and slug for cpt is story-title
 * 
**/
function generate_cpt_rewrite_rules( $wp_rewrite ) {

$event_rules = array(
'story-title/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{1,2})/([0-9]{1,2})/?$' => 'index.php?post_type=storyTitle&year=$matches[1]&monthnum=$matches[2]&day=$matches[3]',
'story-title/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{1,2})/?$' => 'index.php?post_type=storyTitle&year=$matches[1]&monthnum=$matches[2]',
'story-title/([0-9]{4})/?$' => 'index.php?post_type=storyTitle&year=$matches[1]'
);

$wp_rewrite->rules = $event_rules + $wp_rewrite->rules;
}
add_filter( 'generate_rewrite_rules', 'generate_cpt_rewrite_rules' );
```